# Add quotes to delimited fields

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a very big file contain some mix data - total 5 field delimited with pipe. See two sample records here:

```
"1"|"{"Address": "SomeAddress#1", "City": "Tokyo", "Country": "Japan"}"|SomeAddress#1|Tokyo|Japan
"2"|"{"Address": "SomeAddress#2", "City": "Tokyo", "Country": "Japan"}"|SomeAddress#2|Tokyo|Japan
```

I want to quote all the fields from 3 onwards.

The output I am looking for will be:

```
"1"|"{"Address": "SomeAddress#1", "City": "Tokyo", "Country": "Japan"}"|"SomeAddress#1"|"Tokyo"|"Japan"
"2"|"{"Address": "SomeAddress#2", "City": "Tokyo", "Country": "Japan"}"|"SomeAddress#2"|"Tokyo"|"Japan"
```

Can someone guide me either sed or awk to update a 2gb data file quick?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

I was waiting til you provided your attempt in your question but since you have 2 answers already... using any awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) $i="\"" $i "\""} 1' file
```

The above assumes you can't have a `|` inside a quoted field.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/|\([^|]*\)/|"\1"/2g' input_file
"1"|"{"Address": "SomeAddress#1", "City": "Tokyo", "Country": "Japan"}"|"SomeAddress#1"|"Tokyo"|"Japan"

"2"|"{"Address": "SomeAddress#2", "City": "Tokyo", "Country": "Japan"}"|"SomeAddress#2"|"Tokyo"|"Japan"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sed` or `awk`, consider `while read`.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='|' read -ra line ; do
  printf '%s|%s|"%s"|"%s"|"%s"\n' "${line[@]}"
done < file.txt > file.txt.new
# mv file.txt.new file.txt # uncomment to replace the original file with the modified one
```

Comment: That would run for hours given a 2G input file, orders of magnitude longer than an awk script would take. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). It should also have a `&&` between the loop and the `mv` so you don't wipe out the input file if something in  the loop fails, e.g. it runs out of storage.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following `awk` one-liner might work for you:

```
awk -F '|' 'NF {printf "%s|%s|\"%s\"|\"%s\"|\"%s\"\n", $1, $2, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}' your_source_file
```

Split lines on pipe character:
`-F '|'`
Skip empty lines:
`NF`
Output in desired format:
`printf "%s|%s|\"%s\"|\"%s\"|\"%s\"\n", $1, $2, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF`

Sample source file:

```
"1"|"{"Address": "SomeAddress#1", "City": "Tokyo", "Country": "Japan"}"|SomeAddress#1|Tokyo|Japan

"2"|"{"Address": "SomeAddress#2", "City": "Tokyo", "Country": "Japan"}"|SomeAddress#2|Tokyo|Japan
```

Sample output:

```
$ awk -F '|' 'NF {printf "%s|%s|\"%s\"|\"%s\"|\"%s\"\n", $1, $2, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}' s.txt
"1"|"{"Address": "SomeAddress#1", "City": "Tokyo", "Country": "Japan"}"|"SomeAddress#1"|"Tokyo"|"Japan"
"2"|"{"Address": "SomeAddress#2", "City": "Tokyo", "Country": "Japan"}"|"SomeAddress#2"|"Tokyo"|"Japan"
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help - all the suggestions are working perfectly well.